# calling the arc4random method to spawn one enemy but two spawn instead

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spawn, arc4random

Hello I am making a side scrolling cocos2d app where enemies attack a character. I am using arc4random and a switch statement to spawn the enemies one at a time. This should happen but it instead spawns two at a time. I am a beginner in cocos2d and objective c so I may be missing something simple. Any help is valuable though.

Here is the code:

```
#import "FlyingEnemy.h"

@implementation FlyingEnemy
+(id)createEnemies{
return [[[self alloc]init]autorelease];
}

-(id)init{
if((self = [super init])){
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]winSize];
    screenWidth = size.width;
    screenHeight = size.height;

    screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    redEnemyFlameCounter = 1;

    xPoint = screenWidth - 50;
    yPoint = screenHeight/2;

    yellowEnemyFlameCounter = 1;

    blueEnemyFlameCounter = 1;

    xPointBlueEnemy = screenWidth - 50;
    yPointBlueEnemy = screenHeight - 50;

    [self createEnemyOfType];
}
return self;
}

-(void) createEnemyOfType{
randomEnemy = arc4random_uniform(4);
CCLOG(@"the number is %i",randomEnemy);
switch(randomEnemy) {
    case 0: isRedEnemyOnTheScreen = YES;

            redEnemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redenemy.png"];
            redEnemy.position = ccp(xPoint, yPoint);
            [self addChild:redEnemy z:-1];

            [self schedule:@selector(shootTheBullets:)interval:1.0f/2.0f];

            [self schedule: @selector(removeTheEnemy:)interval:18.0f/1.0f];

            [self schedule: @selector(redEnemyFlame:)interval:1.0f/5.0f];

        CCLOG(@"number = %i",randomEnemy);
        break;
    case 1: isYellowEnemyOnTheScreen = YES;

            yellowEnemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yellowenemy.png"];
            yellowEnemy.position = ccp(screenWidth - 50, 50);
            [self addChild:yellowEnemy z:-1];

            yellowEnemyMoveDown  = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(yellowEnemy.position.x, 50)];
            yellowEnemyMoveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(yellowEnemy.position.x, screenHeight/2)];
            yellowEnemyFloatingSequnece = [CCSequence actions:yellowEnemyMoveUp, yellowEnemyMoveDown, nil];
            yellowEnemyFloatingRepeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:yellowEnemyFloatingSequnece times:2];
            [yellowEnemy runAction:yellowEnemyFloatingRepeat];

            [self schedule: @selector(yellowEnemyFlame:)interval:1.0f/5.0f];

        CCLOG(@"number = %i",randomEnemy);
        break;
    case 2: isBlueEnemyOnTheScreen = YES;

            blueEnemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blueenemy.png"];
            blueEnemy.position = ccp(xPointBlueEnemy, yPointBlueEnemy);
            [self addChild:blueEnemy z:-1];

            [self schedule:@selector(shootTheWaterBullets:)interval:1.0f/2.0f];

            CCMoveTo* blueEnemyMoveDown = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0 position:ccp(xPointBlueEnemy, 70)];
            CCMoveTo* blueEnemyMoveUp = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3.0 position:ccp(xPointBlueEnemy, screenHeight - 100)];
            CCSequence* blueEnemyFloatingSequence = [CCSequence actions:blueEnemyMoveDown, blueEnemyMoveUp, nil];
            CCRepeat* blueEnemyFloatingRepeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:blueEnemyFloatingSequence times:3];
            [blueEnemy runAction:blueEnemyFloatingRepeat];

            [self schedule: @selector(removeTheBlueEnemy:)interval:18.0f/1.0f];

            [self schedule: @selector(blueEnemyFlame:)interval:1.0f/5.0f];

        CCLOG(@"number = %i",randomEnemy);
        break;
    case 3 : isSpinningRockOnTheScreen = YES;

            spinningRock = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rocks.png"];
            spinningRock.position = ccp(screenWidth * 1.5, screenHeight/2);
            [self addChild:spinningRock z:-1];

            [spinningRock runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:2.0 angle:360]]];

            moveTheRock = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:39.0 position:ccp(-500, spinningRock.position.y)];
            [spinningRock runAction:moveTheRock];

            [self schedule:@selector(removeTheSpinningRock:)interval:10.0f/1.0f];

        CCLOG(@"number = %i",randomEnemy);
        break;
}
}

-(void)removeTheSpinningRock:(ccTime)delta{
[self unschedule:@selector(removeTheSpinningRock:)];
[self stopAllActions];

[self createEnemyOfType];

isSpinningRockOnTheScreen = NO;
}

-(void)redEnemyFlame:(ccTime)delta{
redEnemyFlameCounter ++;

if (redEnemyFlameCounter % 2){
    [redEnemy setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redenemy2.png"]texture]];
}else{
    [redEnemy setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redenemy.png"]texture]];
}
}

-(void)removeTheEnemy:(ccTime)delta{
CCMoveBy* moveUp = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2.0 position:ccp(100, screenHeight/2)];
[redEnemy runAction:moveUp];
[self unschedule:@selector(removeTheEnemy:)];

[self createEnemyOfType];

isRedEnemyOnTheScreen = NO;
}

-(void)yellowEnemyFlame:(ccTime)delta{
yellowEnemyFlameCounter ++;

if (yellowEnemyFlameCounter % 2){
    [yellowEnemy setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yellowenemy2.png"]texture]];
}else{
    [yellowEnemy setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yellowenemy.png"]texture]];
}
[self schedule:@selector(yellowEnemyFlight:)interval:8.0f/1.0f];

}

-(void)yellowEnemyFlight:(ccTime)delta{
yellowEnemyMoveLeft = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:4.0 position:ccp(-100, bulletY)];
[yellowEnemy runAction:yellowEnemyMoveLeft];

[self schedule:@selector(removeTheYellowEnemy:)interval:4.0f/1.0f];
}

-(void)removeTheYellowEnemy:(ccTime)delta{
CCMoveTo* removeYellowEnemy = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(-100, screenHeight/2)];
[yellowEnemy runAction:removeYellowEnemy];
[self unschedule:@selector(removeTheYellowEnemy:)];

[self createEnemyOfType];

isYellowEnemyOnTheScreen = NO;
}

-(void)blueEnemyFlame:(ccTime)delta{
blueEnemyFlameCounter ++;

if (blueEnemyFlameCounter % 2){
    [blueEnemy setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blueenemy2.png"]texture]];
}else{
    [blueEnemy setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"blueenemy.png"]texture]];
}
}

-(void)removeTheBlueEnemy:(ccTime)delta{
CCMoveBy* moveUpBlueEnemy = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.5 position:ccp(200, 400)];
[blueEnemy runAction:moveUpBlueEnemy];
[self unschedule:@selector(removeTheBlueEnemy:)];

[self createEnemyOfType];

isBlueEnemyOnTheScreen = NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code, are you creating two instances of the FlyingEnemy class somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't create another instance of FlyingEnemy anywhere else. Is there another method like arc4random I can try that may be more reliable?? Is there another way to do what I am doing??

Comment: I don't see that being an issue, it only returns one number. Are the two enemies the same color? Are your log messages being called twice?

Comment: All of the enemies are different. In the output this is what it says. So for some reason the arc4random is generating two numbers. 2013-08-13 22:11:37.152 Zach App[23917:a0b] the number is 3
2013-08-13 22:11:37.163 Zach App[23917:a0b] number = 3
2013-08-13 22:11:37.163 Zach App[23917:a0b] the number is 1
2013-08-13 22:11:37.166 Zach App[23917:a0b] number = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your removeEnemy method, you don't call a corresponding method to remove your child sprite from the scene. Therefore, every time you call that method another CCSprite gets added without one being removed, which is why you are seeing duplicates. Make sure you call removeChild: to remove the CCSprite.

Comment: if I put removeChild in the removeTheEnemy methods then I get a thread bad access error.

Comment: I can't tell how you're declaring your redEnemy variable, but it looks like a strong reference isn't being maintained and the variable is going out of scope. You need to either set an @property that is strong and keep the sprite there, or you can give the sprite a tag and access it that way.

Comment: I used both tags and properties and both of them still returned a thread bad access  error.

Answer (score 1):

If u have a bad access it means your object is nill or if u removed your object from scene and after this u are trying to do something with this object, for example run action on it, it's bad access.